# Media queries não funcionam

Tags: layout-responsivo, media-queries

Fiz essas *medias queries* para Desktop, segue o código abaixo:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) , screen and (min-height: 600px){

    #menu ul {
        left: 26%;
    }
    .nomes{
        margin-top: 200px;
    }

    .botao-circulo{
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-left:-15px;
    }

    #header {
        height: 100%;
    }

    video {
        transform:scaley(1.8);
    }


    #bg-video{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: -50;
        /*  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 200px 100px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);*/
    }


    .image.ico {

        margin-left: 70px;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }

    #fundo-transparente-icones{
        left: -300px;
        top: 90%;
        transform:scale(0.6);
    }

    .botao-mais input[type="button"],.mais{
        margin-left: 175%; 
    }

    .texto-jogos{
        margin-top: 200px;
        margin-left: 50px;
    }


    .botaozao input[type="button"],.jogos-botao{
        margin-left: 15%;
        margin-top: 30px;   

    }

    .botaozao input[type="button"]:hover,.jogos-botao{
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #333;
        transition:0.5s;
    }

    #fundo-transparente-parcerias{
        left: -300px;
        top: 330%;
        transform:scale(0.6);
    }

    .linha-team{
        width: 40%;
        margin-top: -10px;
    }



    #footer .copyright {
        left: 38%;
    }
}


@media screen and(min-width:1024px),screen and(min-height: 768px){
    #fundo-transparente-parcerias{
        left: -300px;
        top: 250%;
        transform:scale(0.6);
    }

    #fundo-transparente-icones{
        left: -300px;
        top: 65%;
        transform:scale(0.6);
    }

}


@media screen and (min-width:1280px),screen and(min-height: 800px){
    /*    #fundo-transparente-icones{
            left: -180px;
            top: 85%;
            transform:scale(0.7);
        }

         #fundo-transparente-parcerias{
            left: -180px;
            top: 265%;
            transform:scale(0.7);
        }*/

}

@media screen and (min-width:1366px),screen and(min-height: 768px){
    /*    #fundo-transparente-icones{
            left: -180px;
            top: 90%;
            transform:scale(0.7);
        }

         #fundo-transparente-parcerias{
            left: -180px;
            top: 275%;
            transform:scale(0.7);
        }*/

}

@media screen and (min-width:1440px),screen and(min-height: 900px){
    #menu ul {
        left: 26%;
    } 
}


@media screen and (min-width:1600px),screen and(min-height: 900px){
    #menu ul {
        left: 32%;
    } 

    .setas{
        position: absolute;
        top: 60px;
        left: 14%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:1680px),screen and(max-height: 1050px){
    .botaozao input[type="button"],.jogos-botao{
        margin-left: 15%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1920px),screen and(min-height: 1080px){
    .botaozao input[type="button"],.jogos-botao{
        margin-left: 13%;
    }

    #bg-video{
       width: 100%;
    }

    video {
        transform:scaleY(1.8);
        transform: scaleX(1.2);
    }

     .setas{
        left: 18%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1920px),screen and(min-height: 1200px){
    .botaozao input[type="button"],.jogos-botao{
        margin-left: 13%;
    }

    #bg-video{
       width: 100%;
    }

     .setas{
        left: 18%;
    }
}
```

Porem quando fui fazer para tablets, elas simplesmente não implementam, antes ela bagunçava todas as *media queries* que eu já havia feito que tive uma resolução disso em um tópico anterior porem agora não quer aplicar. Segue abaixo um dos códigos da medida que não aplica:

```
@media screen and(max-width:533px),screen and(max-height: 853px){
    #menu ul {
        left: 0px;
    }

    #menu ul li a{

        font-size: 1.2em;
        margin: 4px;
    }

    #seta-esquerda{
        right: 35px;
    }

    #seta-direita{
        left: 35px;
    }

    video {
        transform:scaley(3.4);
    }

    .nomes{
        font-size: 4.3em;
        margin-top: 200px;
    }

    .texto1 {
        font-size: 1em;
    }

    .image.ico {

        margin: 0 0 1em 0;
        width: 50%;
        margin-left: 175px;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }

    .image.ico img {
        width: 60%;
    }

    .botao-mais input[type="button"],.mais{
        margin-left: 80%; 
    }

    #fundo-transparente-icones{
        position: absolute;
        left: -180px;
        top: 80%;
        transform:scale(0.8);
        z-index: -200;
    }

    .main .jogos-nomes{
        margin-top: 50px;
        font-size: 3.5em;
    }

    .texto-jogos{
        text-align: left;
        font-family: Gabriola;
        font-size: 1em;
        margin-top: 120px;
        margin-left: 40px;
    }



    .main {
        padding: 6em 0 4em 0;
    }



    .main.style2 {
        background-color: #333;
        color:#fff;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        height: 600px;
        opacity: 0.95;
        border-bottom: 15px solid #f80;
        border-top: 15px solid #f80;

    }

    .main.style2{
        background-repeat: no-repeat;

    }

    .botaozao input[type="button"],.jogos-botao{
        background-color: transparent;
        color: #fff;
        width: 250px;
        height: 50px;
        border:3px solid #fff;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: 20%;
        margin-top: 30px;   
        border-radius: 6px;
        font-family: Gabriola;
        font-size: 1.7em;

    }

    .botaozao input[type="button"]:hover,.jogos-botao{
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #333;
        transition:0.5s;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`media screen` serve para Desktop (e nexus) só, está aqui uma lista de todas as [media-queries espeficicas que podes usar](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) no entanto, se usares só `@media (max-width:NNpx)` ela irá funcionar sem grande problema :)

Comment: poxa amigo obrigado pela resposta ai "rsrs" nunca imaginaria que funcionasse assim.

Answer (score 3):

Já tentou assim `@media (max-width:533px)` ? 
Caso não dê certo, so vendo o estilo completo para poder indicar algo.

Comment: obrigado você também pela ajuda marquei o dele como resposta porque ele respondeu primeiro mais muito obrigado também pela ajuda